# Запретить распространение кода полностью или частично

Tags: лицензирование

Здравствуйте! Интересует вопрос по поводу лицензии, запрещающей распространение исходных кодов программы в любом виде.

Есть небольшой проект, над которым мы работаем в команде, и не хотелось бы, что бы какой-нибудь человек из команды, в случае если по какой-либо **уважительной** причине(отсутствие активности в проекте, нарушение правил и т.д.)  его придется "выкинуть" из команды. Наша команда нигде и никак не зарегистрирована, все держится только на доверительных отношениях, но случиться может всякое, поэтому хотелось бы перестраховаться

Если у кого-нибудь есть текст лицензии, был бы благодарен, если бы ею поделились.

Так же было бы неплохо иметь версию на английском языке, так как весь проект выполнен на нем же(комментарии, баг-трекинг и т.д.)

Comment: `Наша команда нигде и никак не зарегистрирована, все держится только на доверительных отношениях,` навряд ли будет принято судом при рассмотрении дела об авторстве.

Comment: Вредный совет: выложить все исходники под GPL, тогда не нужно будет париться по поводу того, что кто-то другой их выложит (типа шутка))

Comment: если у вас есть лидер, то можете закопирайтить весь код на него, если он сойдет с ума и поссорится с вами, правда, останетесь без ничего

Comment: А как собираетесь определять, что это _вы_ выкинули кого-то из команды, а не этот _кто-то_ выкинул всех остальных?

Comment: @strangeqargo "Лидер" - это я. А не подскажите, как именно можно сделать это? Какая лицензия нужна в таком случае? НЕ Open-Source

Comment: @leon0399 самое близкое из ответов - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/68134/best-existing-license-for-closed-source-code, остальное к юристам, на самом деле